# Exposing a Web Service with a proxy

Tags: java, web-services, soap

I exposing a SOAP Web Service. My web service runs on server1 the WSDL End point generates soap address as below.

```
<soap:address location="http://server:87/service1"/>
```

My web service can be accessed via  http://server1:87/service1?wsdl.

This is not good since outside world can see my real server name address.

Server can be mapped to alias name where the solution can accessed with 
http://myserver/service1.

But WSDL

How Can I setup SOAP address location explicitly by my selves without WSDL to determine the SOAP address location ? 
I like to see the tag as

where it shows me with real server details